# How to remove/add or disable/enable items in BIOS "Boot Priority Order"?

Tags: bios

I am trying to delete "SD Card 1" from the list but it won't work. I pressed 'del' several times, exit out with saved changes, rebooted but its still there. Can someone please help me?
[image]

Comment: Read the note: "Del deletes an *unprotected* device." Apparently, SD card is "protected", so disable it.

Comment: I tried disabling it too but it doesn't do anything. I literally pressed 'Shift + 1' and it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DrMoishe is correct. You cannot remove it because the device is protected. Instructions are a bit vague in the bios screenshot so I wasn't able to figure it out. I was able to disable it though by pressing 'Shift' + '!'. I was mislead by 'Shift + 1'. DO NOT USE NUMBER KEYPAD FOR PRESSING 1. IT IS EXPECTING EXCLAMATION. I hope this helps!

Comment: I don't understand this answer to be honest.  `Shift !` and `Shift 1` are the same key combination though.  They are literally the same key and ! is a shift operation of the 1 key.

Comment: @Ramhound, not on every layout. For  eg. BEPO layout and Berber/Morrocan layout. Again, I don't know what layout the OP is using, but there are layouts which don't have the ! and 1 key together.

Comment: @Inxsible - Which is the reason I am attempting to get clarification for the community.

Comment: My guess is, that the BIOS note could have just said -- `! enables or disables a device` and let the user figure out how to type the ! mark in their keyboard layout instead of suggesting `SHIFT + 1 enables or disables a device` because like @Dheeraj Dixit, you could choose to use the Num pad and it won't work.

Comment: @Inxsible - that is exactly right. If it was ! enables or disables a device then I would have figure it out right away.